# SQLite3 haskell createFunction example

Tags: haskell, sqlite, create-function

Here's the SQLite3 Haskell bindings  with the ability to create function: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/sqlite/0.5.1/doc/html/Database-SQLite.html

But I can't get to use this feature, I wrote the code like this:

```
increment a = a + 1

checkout = do
       handle <- openConnection "test.db"
       ok <- createFunction handle "woot" (IsFunctionHandler increment)

       return $ execStatement handle "SELECT woot(5)";
```

But it isn't compile with "Not in scope: data constructor `IsFunctionHandler'" error

---

The correct code is:

```
module Test where

import Database.SQLite
import Int

increment :: Int64 -> Int64
increment a = a + 1

checkout :: IO (Either String [[Row Value]])
checkout = do
       handle <- openConnection "test.db"
       ok <- createFunction handle "woot" increment

       execStatement handle "SELECT woot(5), woot(7), woot(128)"
```

Thanks to HaskellElephant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsFunctionHandler` is a class, not a data constructor. It has several [instances](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/sqlite/0.4.2/doc/html/Database-SQLite.html#t%3AIsFunctionHandler) so if `increment` is an instance of `IsFunctionHandler`, wich it in this case is, you should be able to write:

```
createFunction handle "woot" increment
```

Comment: Yep, thanks, I just got messed with all this typeclasses and instances, thanks :) I post the correct code in the question.